# Open "Network Connections" within explorer from batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How can I open the following explorer window with a batch file:

```
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
```

I am using the following within my batch file currently:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections"
```

But this seems to open up the default of the My Documents folder.

- What do I have to do to open this location in explorer? It seems to be different syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
control ncpa.cpl
```

or

```
control netconnections
```

Control panel items are opened by running control.exe with a cpl name as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the OP, adding here since this page is high in SEO

To add a quick-link to "Network Connections" from the right-click context menu on the "Network" icon (in Windows Explorer) showing as "Adapter Settings", this can be added to the registry (usual safety concerns apply).

At the command-line:

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\shell\Adapter Settings\command" /d "control netconnections" /t REG_SZ /f
```

(that is one line, watch for line-wrap in the web page)

Or manually add the keys/values.  You will probably need to take Ownership and Full Control of the {F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C} key first.

In turn, I have been showing the "Network" icon on the desktop for the servers I administer (just like the good 'ol days when it was so easy to get at the screens and settings I needed).

While you are at it, you could also add a quick-link to "Advanced Firewall And Security":

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\shell\Advanced Firewall and Security\command" /d "%%SystemRoot%%\system32\mmc.exe %%SystemRoot%%\system32\wf.msc" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f
```